# Should I be using process.nextTick

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to get my head around when to use process.nextTick. Below I'm using async library to control my code flow and was wondering if I should be calling nextTick in the end callback or not.

```
async.parallel([
    function (callback) {
        // do something
        callback(data);
    },
    function (callback) {
        // do something
        callback(data);        
    }
], 
// callback
function (data) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
        // do something
    });
});
```

Comment: What's making you think you should call `nextTick` there?

Comment: I read this [article about nextTick](http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick) and one of the examples in there was about making callbacks asynchronous. So I was wondering should I be thinking about making use of nextTick on all callbacks to avoid potential future issues if the server is heavily loaded. My test worked fine with and without the use of nextTick - so still trying to wrap my head around when it's best used.

Comment: It's actually pretty simple.  Only use `nextTick` when you want to defer execution of some code until after the current callback is done executing and any already queued callbacks have been run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what your 'do something' is, I don't see any reason that you'd need to use `nextTick` in this situation.  You use `nextTick` when you have reason to defer execution of a function to the next iteration of the event loop.  You might want to read [Understanding `process.nextTick`](http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick) for more detail.

Also, note that async's `parallel` task completion callbacks take arguments `err, data`, so you should be doing:

```
async.parallel([
    function (callback) {
        // do something
        callback(null, data);
    },
    function (callback) {
        // do something
        callback(null, data);        
    }
], 
// callback
function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // do something
});
```

The major difference being that the final callback is invoked immediately if one of the parallel tasks returns an error (calls `callback` with a truthy first argument).

Comment: I do have one question - is a call automatically async if it has a callback?  Are all callbacks placed into the node event loop or are there cases where just having a callback will NOT make a process in node async?

Comment: Not necessarily.  A callback is simply a function that gets called "later" -- there's nothing intrinsically special about it; it's just simple function invocation, and callbacks are not automatically scheduled on the event loop (in fact, that's what you might use `nextTick` for).  Of course, what "later" means is entirely up to the function you pass a callback to.  For example, `function (cb) { cb(); }` is not asynchronous because you *know* that the callback will be invoked immediately, on the same call stack, and in the same iteration of the event loop.

Comment: ... This is not necessarily bad though: consider a function that retrieves data from a database, but also caches data.  `function get(key, cb) { if(cache[key]) cb(cache[key]); else getFromDb(key, function(dbresult) { cache[key]=dbresult; cb(dbresult); }); }`  The function returns data *synchronously* if it is cached (this is good: it makes your program faster), or *asynchronously* if it needs to fetch the data from the database.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  But how does node decide what gets put on the event loop and what isn't?  Is it only IO or processes wrapped by nexttick that are put into the loop.  For example, if I have a set of 5 callbacks (one calling another) are they all called synchronously unless I use Nexttick or make an IO call?

Comment: Generally, anything that happens on another thread (like I/O) or callbacks passed to `nextTick`, `setTimeout`, and `setInterval` are queued for invocation on the next run of the event loop.

Comment: @josh3763 I would consider an implementation in the style of your async DB access example a nightmare. When implementing an API (like a DB access wrapper), inconsistent callback invocation can lead to subtle and obtuse bugs. If a function accepts a callback, it should *always* be implemented consistently one way or the other.

I shared your opinion until I came across this article about releasing Zalgo: http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that for `async.parallel` and other similar functions to work correctly, that you **need** to make all tasks definitely asynchronous; I love the async lib and it's my #1 choice over promises etc, but there can be some weird behavior if you don't force tasks to be async.

See here:
https://github.com/caolan/async#common-pitfalls-stackoverflow

so it should be:

```
async.parallel([

function(cb){
   process.nextTick(function(){
          doSomePotentiallySyncThing(cb);
   });
},

function(cb){
   process.nextTick(function(){
          doSomePotentiallySyncThing(cb);
   });
},
function(cb){

     definitelyAsync(cb);  // if it's **definitely** async, then we don't need process.nextTick

}
], function complete(err, results){

    // we are in the final callback

});
```

I am 99% sure about this.